# Is there a relatively elementary proof that the gamma function has no zero?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

I have never studied functional analysis. So I am unable to understand terms such as meromorphic, holomorphic and etc.

So far, I have showed Gauss', Euler's , Weierstrass' definition of the Gamma function are identical.

I have proved that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)=\Gamma(z+w)B(z,w)$ too where $Re(z),Re(w)>0$.

I think the proof in the link below is elementary if i could understand, but i think proof here does not make sense.. If so, please explain me how exactly..

(Link : http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Gamma_Function)

Comment: The proof is fairly easy to understand if you accept the Euler form of $\Gamma(z)$. What is it that you're having trouble with? Also, holomorphic and meromorphic are terms generally used within complex analysis.

Comment: @D.Clark Clark I have neither learned complex analysis. I have learned real analysis that's it. How do i exactly show that $\Gamma(z)\neq 0$ from the Euler's second integral?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know you haven't yet studied complex analysis before I wrote my answer...

Comment: @DonAntonio Dear Don. Does the proof in the link make sense?

Comment: Well, the Euler form, which is the one used in the Bohr-Mollerup theorem (which is a pearl in itself and does *not* require complex analysis to understand it, only advanced real analysis) is pretty clear there, though the argument is not that clear to me (and less at these hours). Yet I think it is, or can be put in a form as to be, basically true.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know the Bohr-Mollerup theorem, but isn't it only true for the gamma function with *real* domain?

Comment: Yes @Number9...but then "analytic continuation" kicks in and things get swell for complex variable...but this perhaps is out of your actual reach.

Comment: @DonAntonio Would you please check the answer i wrote? is it correct?

Comment: See [Gamma function has no zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/606307/127096).

Comment: @127.0.9.6 I saw that post before i post my question. I couldn't understand it though.. what is holomorphic..?

Comment: There is a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) about that. I think that most people learn what a holomorphic function is before they begin to worry about whether $\Gamma$ has zeros in the complex plain...

Answer (score 3):

By [Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) , we have that

$$\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac\pi{\sin\pi z}$$

This clearly shows the function cannot vanish (unless it'd vanish at $\;z\;$ **and also** it'd have a pole in $\;1-z\;$ with the same residue, which doesn't happen as the poles of the function are *only* at the non-positive integers...)

Answer (score 2):

An infinite product $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1+a_{j})$ of complex numbers $a_{j}\ne -1$ converges to a non-zero complex number if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{j}| < \infty$. This applies to your case because, if $z \ne -1,-2,\ldots$,
$$
        \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{z}}{\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)}=1+\frac{z(z-1)}{2n^{2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z)>0$

Then $\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/n)^z}{1+z/n}$ (Euler Form)

Suppose $\Gamma(z)=0$

Then, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/n)^{Re(z)}}{|n+z|/n} = 0$

Since the Euler form is true for $Re(z)$ too, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+Re(z)}{|n+z|}=0$

(Note that this limit exists)

Let $M$ be a positive integer such that $|Im(z)|<M$.

Then, $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+, |z+n|\leq |z|+n \leq Re(z)+|Im(z)|+n < Re(z)+M+n$

Hence,  $1\leq \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{Re(z)+M+n}{|z+n|}$

Hence,  $0<\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{Re(z)+n}{|z+n|}$

Contradiction

===

Edit:

Note that $0<\Gamma(Re(z))=\frac{1}{Re(z)} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/n)^{Re(z)}}{1+Re(z)/n}$

From the Euler second integral, it's direct to check that the limit on the right-hand side is nonzero.

Hence, $0< \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/n)^{Re(z)}}{1+Re(z)/n}$

Multiply the inverse of this limit to the limit in the 4th line, which yields $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+Re(z)}{|n+z|}=0$

Comment: Where does the Re(z) exponent in the 4th line come from?

Comment: @DonAntonio Absolute value of $|\Gamma(z)z|$ on the second line.

Comment: Since the limit in the second line converges to 0, it converges to 0 absolutely.

Comment: I see what I asked, I cannot though follow  the other parts' logic now: why "converges to zero" means "converges to zero abs."? Why that limit exists (6th line)? From where the 5th line?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm really glad that you take time to help me. Thank you. I have added an explanation below.

Comment: Since if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to 0, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n\geq N \Rightarrow |a_n|<\epsilon$. Hence, $\{|a_n|\}$ converges to 0 too.