# Gamma function as the ratio of two holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, gamma-function, meromorphic-functions

**Prelude**

Be $U \subset X$, where $U$ is open and $X$ is a complex manifold.

A meromorphic function $f$ over $U$ is a holomorphic function over $U \backslash S$ (Where $\bar{S}$ has no interior) such that $\exists$ an open cover of $U$ ($U = \bigcup_i U_i$) and
$$f\Big|_{U_i} = \dfrac{g_i}{h_i}$$
where $g_i$ and $h_i$ are holomorphic functions over $U_i$.

**Question**

How can I apply this definition to the meromorphic Gamma Function? That is, what are two functions $g_i$ and $h_i$ such that
$$\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{g}{h}$$

Any reference will be appreciated!

Comment: $1/\Gamma(z)$ is an entire function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688034/42969.