# Is the factorial of any number equal to zero?

Tags: factorial

Was playing around on desmos and discovered that the graph of x! = y does   not interact with zero at any point. Was wondering if any maybe complex number or number that desmos didn't properly compute who's factorial equals zero.

Keep in mind I am just a highschool student so I might not understand some terminology

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: It is true that the standard generalisation of factorial has no zeroes. $z\mapsto1/z!$ defines an entire function of the complex plane

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606307/399263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is flawed because factorial is only defined for $\mathbb{N}_0$. Since $0!=1$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}, x!>(x-1)!$, clearly there are no zeros.

Desmos actually display the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) when one inputs $y=x!$. There are many proofs online as to why the Gamma function has no zeros.